# The matrix commute with A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A,B \in M_n\left( F \right) $, $F$ is a field, and the matrix commute with $A$,$B$ are only $cE$,the $E$ is unit matrix ,$c\in F$ ,what property the matrix $A$ and $B$ will have?

$1$.I know when a matrix $A$ when it Frobenius canonical form have only one Frobenius block，the matrix commute with $A$ can be represent as the ploynomial of $A$,I wonder if the Frobenius canonical form of $A$,$B$ are both have only one Frobenius block,but I find $f(A)=g(B)$ may happen,then the matrix commute with $A,B$ will more than $cE$.

$2$.Find some $A,B$ satisfy the property is easy: we can let $A$ is diagonal,$
\left( \begin{matrix}
 \lambda _1&  &  \\
 &  ...&  \\
 &  &  \lambda _n\\
\end{matrix} \right) 
$

$
\lambda _1,...,\lambda _n
$
are all different,and $B$ is a matrix which Frobenius canonical form have only one Frobenius block,but B can't diagonal,then the matrix commute with $A,B$ are only $cE$.

Thank you for sharing your idea.

Comment: What is $E$ here?

Comment: Oh,it's the unit matrix